# How to map Nhibernate collection

Tags: nhibernate, collections

I have `customer` and `BankAccount` tables. `CustomerID` is a foreign key in the `BankAccount` table. Here we have to do with one to many relationship. I have done mapping for `CustomerInfo` and `BankAccountInfo`. I have attached with the question post.

Here we want to do with collection using `Iesi.collections`. Does anyone have ideas on how to do this in Nhibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do *Collection* mapping start reading this documentation: [Chapter 6. Collection Mapping](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections)

In case that you will use the `Iesi` collections, most suitable could be `ISet<>`, which is designed to allow only unqiue values to be inserted:

```
public class Customer
{
  public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<BankAccount> BankAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping could be like this

```
<set name="BankAccounts" inverse="true" lazy="true" table="BankAccount" 
   cascade="all" batch-size="25" >
 <key column="CustomerId" />
 <one-to-many class="BankAccount" />
</set>
```

Notes: This mapping has some *redundant* attributes, which can help to do smarter loading. E.g. batch-size will avoid 1+N loads, while doing 1 + N/25... cascade will implicitly solve the persistence of added items... read more in doc.

The complete ISet description: http://ayende.com/blog/3943/nhibernate-mapping-set